# How to get complete linking command instead of just CCLD / How to disable silent rules in make file

Tags: linux, linker, libtool

I am currently building an app and getting error in linking, here is a command,

```
CCLD   Programs/GtkBonker
```

Now I want see the **Complete linking Command**, Any help is appreciated.

PS.
I am using GNU Build System with c++ programming language, with Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Would you please be a bit more specific? Which programming language and compilation toolkit are you using?

Comment: @difnor.sign, I have now edited question. Thanks

Comment: Its tagged as libtool and it said `CCLD` so its pretty obvious that its C used with the GNU Build System.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to see full commands or say want to disable silent rules in webkit,

There are two ways, you can choose the one which suites your scenario

1).you need to run make command with argument V=1,

like this.

**make V=1**

2). pass --disable-silent-rules in configure as an argument.

like this

**configure --disable-silent-rules**

Answer (score 2):

If it uses autoconf, it should be something along the lines of:

```
./configure --disable-silent-rules
```

to get the longer rules.

Comment: It is **--disable-silent-rules**.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Editing that in, couldn't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: Wait, if I recall, autoconf makes --disable-x a synonym for --enable-x=no